# Regex wildcard quick help needed

Tags: regex, powershell

Trying to remove part of the URL from the string:
https://test.com:443/api/DC/XYZ

expected result:
XYZ

tried:

```
$Pattern = "https*DC/"
$New = ""
$dc = [regex]::replace($dc, $pattern, "")
"We will now replace $Pattern with $New :" 
$dc
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dot `.` before the asterisk:

```
$Pattern = "https.*DC/"
$New = ""
$dc = [regex]::replace($dc, $pattern, "")
"We will now replace $Pattern with $New :" 
$dc
}
```